# Qt 6.5 LTS build from source failed - Compiler can't find class headers like QFile

Tags: build, qt6

I'm trying to build qt-everywhere-src-6.5.0 and qt-everywhere-src-6.5.1 for host PC and during the build process, it gives error like below.

```
fatal error: QFile: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <QFile>
```

If I try to replace the include line with absolute path for qfile.h, compiling will continue from there but then the issue comes for another file for different or same header file. Can anypne help me with this?

Also I'm keep getting the following warning message for many header files starting from build.

```
WARNING: /opt/qtCross/qt-everywhere-src-6.5.0/qttools/src/assistant/help/qcompressedhelpinfo.h does not include QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
```

This issue does not seem to come with qt-everywhere-src-6.5.0-rc. I was able to succesfully compile it.

Really apreciate if anyone can help me with this.

I'm in Ubuntu 22.10

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Reported [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-113771) and workaround is to use **qt-everywhere-src-6.5.1.tar.xz** file without using zip file.